# Session in Multipeer-Connectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

There is four devices A、B、C and D，A connect with B and C connect with D and A connect with C but distance between B and C is too long to connect.

1. Is A and C in the same session?
2. Is B and D in the same session?
3. How they communication in the session?
4. According to the reference of MCSession，sessions currently support up to 8 peers，but there is more then 8 peers，how does it work?

Comment: For your question #4: Each `MCSession` supports up to 8 peers, but you can have as many `MCSession` instances as you want. You just need some custom bridge code to pass messages from one session to another when necessary.